# Acknowledgment section, grammar check when thanking previous people who helped me get to this point

Tags: grammar

I am working on the acknowledgment section of my Ph.D. thesis and in the last line I say:

> Lastly, I would like to thank all faculty members at XYX College of Engineering & Applied Science for all their help including during my bachelor's and master's studies.

**Context**:

I received my B.S. and M.S. and hopefully Ph.D. (it's in progress, haven't defended it yet) from the same university and I want to thank the all faculty members in my university starting from when I was a bachelor's student.

**Question**:

Is "including during my bachelor's and master's studies" correct? in terms of both grammar and the meaning I am trying to convey.

Comment: Someone who is a professor at a university is called a "faculty member"; the "faculty" of a university is all its professors (meaning: those who are hired to teach and/or do research there). You probably want to thank "faculty members" (not "faculties").

Comment: Congratulations on finishing your thesis! Raw "proofreading" questions (is-this-correct) are not [on-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Please edit your question to point to a specific grammatical concern in the sentence (personally, I think the wording is fine, but I would set off the final clause with a comma).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a number of ways of thanking the faculty members, but I encourage you not to use the overused "Lastly," and "would like to thank." Instead of "Lastly," how about

- In conclusion,
- Finally,
- Last,
- And last,
- To conclude,

Instead of "I would like to thank," how about

- I extend my thanks to
- Thank you to
- I offer my heartfelt thanks to
- I must thank

Here are a few alternate ways of wording your sentence:

- In conclusion, I extend my thanks to all the faculty members at XYX College of Engineering & Applied Science who helped me during my bachelor's and master's studies.
- And last, I offer my heartfelt thanks to all the faculty members . . . who helped me during my bachelor's and master's studies.
- To conclude, I must thank all the faculty members . . . who helped me during my bachelor's and master's studies.
- Finally, I have to thank all the faculty members . . . who gave me invaluable help during my bachelor's and master's studies

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Why is "lastly" worse than the other options you offer?

Comment: @StuartF: I guess because I find the "ly" unnecessary, as is the "ly" in firstly, secondly, thirdly, etc. In other words, personal preference. Don

Comment: @Node.JS: You're welcome! Don